# How do I chain unique work in WorkManager?

Tags: androidx, android-workmanager

I have just discovered [Unique Work](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/managing-work) which is apparently:

> a powerful concept that guarantees that you only have one instance of work with a particular name at a time.

However, I can't figure out how to chain another piece of work after this.

```kotlin
val workRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<MyWorker>().build()
val operation = workManager.enqueueUniqueWork(UNIQUE_WORK_NAME, ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, workRequest)
// Can't do anything with operation and ensureUniqueWork doesn't take `workContinuation`
```

---

**With the alternative construct, I can't use Unique Work, but this works:**

```kotlin
val workRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<MyWorker>().build()
var workContinuation = workManager.beginWith(workRequest)

val workRequestTwo = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<MyWorkerTwo>().build()
workContinuation = workContinuation.then(work)

workContinuation.enqueue()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `beginUniqueWork`, the function takes a list of sequential work instead of calling `.then`. You are effectively giving the unique work name to the entire chain (3rd argument), not just a single work.

```kotlin
val workRequestOne = ...
val workRequestTwo = ...
val workRequests = listOf(workRequestOne, workRequestTwo)
workManager.beginUniqueWork("Unique work name", ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, workRequests).enqueue()
```

Comment: I think i'm strongly disagree with this answer, you have an important mistake - list of workers that is passed to function `beginUniqueWork` is parallel, but not sequential.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer seems wrong to me. As indicated by @nick's comment.
the right answer should be

```
val workRequestOne = ...
val workRequestTwo = ...
workManager.beginUniqueWork("Unique work name", ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, workRequestOne).then(workRequestTwo).enqueue()
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer will not execute all the works in sequential order. For sequential execution, it should be `ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND` instead of `ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE` like given below.

```
val workRequestOne = ...
val workRequestTwo = ...
val workRequests = listOf(workRequestOne, workRequestTwo)
workManager.beginUniqueWork("Unique work name", ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND, workRequests).enqueue()
```